# Topological semantics (subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ with standard topology) for first-order minimal logic

Tags: logic

Is it possible to give first-order minimal logic a topological semantics of roughly the same flavor as the subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ construction for intuitionistic propositional calculus (IPC)?

I tried, but got stuck on the semantics for $\exists$. I'm interested in a construction that works for minimal logic specifically, but one that works for both IPC and minimal logic is also interesting.

---

Intuitionistic logic has the following [topological semantics as a subset of the real line $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with the standard topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_logic#Heyting_algebra_semantics).

We can describe IPC by translating its connectives into S4 recursively in the following way, which makes the correspondence with the topological semantics clear. Our truth values in this semantic consist of all the elements of $2^\mathbb{R}$. The value $\mathbb{R}$ is designated; all proper subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are non-designated.

$$ \begin{matrix} \textbf{IPC} & \textbf{Modal Logic (S4)} & \textbf{Topology} \\ a \land b & \lnot (\lnot a \lor \lnot b) & (a^c \cup a^c)^c \\
a \lor b & a \lor b & a \cup b \\
a \to b & \square(\lnot a \lor b) & \text{int}(a^c \cup b) \\
\top & \top & \mathbb{R} \\
\bot & \lnot\top & \mathbb{R}^c \end{matrix} $$

According to the [Wikipedia article on minimal logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_logic), minimal logic corresponds to the positive fragment of intuitionistic propositional calculus.

> As minimal logic represents only the positive fragment of intuitionistic logic, it is a subsystem of intuitionistic logic and is strictly weaker.

The article then goes on to say that $\bot$ is treated like an ordinary proposition in minimal logic. Let $F$ be a fixed variable symbol that is not used in IPC. I think we can use the following translation to convert minimal logic to IPC. I am unsure about the translation of $\to$.

$$ \begin{matrix} \textbf{Minimal Logic} & \textbf{IPC} \\
a \land b & a \land b \\
a \lor b & a \lor b \\
a \to b & a \to b \\
\top & \top \\
\bot & F \;\; \text{where $F$ is a fixed variable symbol} \\
 \end{matrix} $$

So far, so good. I am now going to attempt to define $\forall$ in minimal logic and translate it into the topological semantics. Let $D$ be the domain of discourse. $\varphi$ is a well-formed formula. Let's suppose that our first-order language $\textbf{First-order minimal logic}$ has predicate symbols that map finite sequences of fixed length to subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, but does not have a notion of constant or function symbols.

$$ \begin{matrix} \textbf{First-order Minimal Logic} & \textbf{S4} & \textbf{Topology} \\
\forall x \mathop. \varphi(x) &  \lnot \bigvee_{x \in D} \lnot \varphi(x) & (\bigcup_{x \in D} \varphi(x)^c)^c
\end{matrix} $$

This is pretty good. Because $\mathbb{R}$ is the only designated truth value and we are taking the intersection of a family of sets, each of which is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, we end up with $\mathbb{R}$ as our resulting truth value if and only if all the sets in our family are $\mathbb{R}$. This fits what we would want the truth-conditions of $\forall$ to be.

$\exists$, however, is much harder. Here's the simplest thing that could possibly work.

$$ \begin{matrix} \textbf{BAD!} & \textbf{First-order Minimal Logic} & \textbf{S4} & \textbf{Topology} \\
{} & \exists x \mathop. \varphi(x) & \bigvee_{x \in D} \varphi(x) & \bigcup_{x \in D} \varphi(x)
\end{matrix} $$

This construction gives $\exists$ the wrong truth conditions. If $\varphi$ evaluates to $\{ x : x < 0 \}$ one time and $\{x : x \ge 0\}$ another time and never evaluates to $\varnothing$ otherwise, then $\exists x \mathop. \varphi(x)$ will be true because the two non-empty truth values *fill in each other's gaps despite the fact that neither is designated*.

One idea I can think of for how to fix this is introducing a notion of strong negation that sends every non-designated truth value to $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ to $\varnothing$. That would allow me use $ \bigcup_{x \in D} \sim \sim x $ where $\sim$ is strong negation. This doesn't *feel very topological*, however.

Another idea I sort of have is switching from $\mathbb{R}$ to something like an [excluded point topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excluded_point_topology) or something similar where every open set that isn't the whole space lacks a specific point and then taking the interior of $\varphi(x)$ for all $x$ but I'm not sure how to make the idea work.

Comment: Why are you writing intersections as complements of unions of complements?

Comment: @AlexKruckman I'm trying to keep the number of distinct connectives in the intermediate S4 translation step as small as possible (without doing something too weird like using nand) and to have the notation for the semantics match the modal logic as closely as possible.

Comment: Don't the usual topological semantics for intuitionistic logic take truth values in the open sets only?

Comment: That's a good point. I don't know. In the topological semantics of S4, you can produce a closed set with $\lnot$ ... so I thought everything in $2^\mathbb{R}$ had to be in our set of truth values because the IPC construction is the same as what you would get if you translated into S4 first...  When translating IPC to S4, if I encounter a primitive propositional variable $v$, do I translate it to $\square v$?